# jQuery - How to add class to an element, depending on what the string is

Tags: jquery, string, text, selector

Using jQuery, how to add class to an element in table, depending on what the string is?

For example, I have a table like this:

```js
$('td:contains("Big pineapple!")').addClass('big-pineapple');
```

```css
.big-pineapple {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-one">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Where are you</th>
        <th>What are you</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds</td>
        <td>Alfreds@Alfreds.com</td>
        <td>I'm here</td>
        <td>Big pineapple!</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Maria</td>
        <td>Maria@Maria.com</td>
        <td>I used to be there</td>
        <td>A lamp</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Anders</td>
        <td>Anders@Anders.com</td>
        <td>Why you ask</td>
        <td>Big pineapple!</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Island</td>
        <td>Island@Island.com</td>
        <td>I don't even know</td>
        <td>Big pineapple!</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Matt</td>
        <td>Matt@Matt.com</td>
        <td>Everywhere</td>
        <td>Not Big pineapple!</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

So I want to add classes based purely on what the string is. So in this example, I what to addClass **big-pineapple** to each field that has text **Big pineapple!**

I can catch it like that with contains selector, but I would like to match it if that's the only thing in text (so not in the last part where text is **Not Big pineapple!**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a selector that, but you can do it with `filter` and check the `html()` of each `td`.

```js
var f =$('td').filter(function(i,o) { return $(o).html() === 'Big pineapple!' });
f.addClass('big-pineapple');
```

```css
.big-pineapple {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-one">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Where are you</th>
        <th>What are you</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds</td>
        <td>Alfreds@Alfreds.com</td>
        <td>I'm here</td>
        <td>Big pineapple!</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Maria</td>
        <td>Maria@Maria.com</td>
        <td>I used to be there</td>
        <td>A lamp</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Anders</td>
        <td>Anders@Anders.com</td>
        <td>Why you ask</td>
        <td>Big pineapple!</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Island</td>
        <td>Island@Island.com</td>
        <td>I don't even know</td>
        <td>Big pineapple!</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Matt</td>
        <td>Matt@Matt.com</td>
        <td>Everywhere</td>
        <td>Not Big pineapple!</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that will do it. Just one question, will filter bring any heavy load if I have over 100 of the similar functions?